# configure Params contain with axios in vue for filter json file with json server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I use `json-server` with Vue.js

```
json-server --watch tareas.json
```

And this is my JSON file:

```
{
  "tareas": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "titulo": "254",
      "finished": true
    },
    {
      "titulo": "2316345",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 6
    },
    {
      "titulo": "561321654",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 8
    },
    {
      "titulo": "2165161",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 9
    },
    {
      "titulo": "25",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 10
    },
    {
      "titulo": "11",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 14
    },
    {
      "titulo": "21651",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 17
    },
    {
      "id": 20,
      "titulo": "25",
      "finished": true
    },
    {
      "titulo": "25",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 21
    },
    {
      "titulo": "125",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 24
    },
    {
      "titulo": "5256",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 25
    }
  ]
}
```

I create an input in my Home.vue

```
<input type="text" v-model="filtrosTitulo" @keyup.enter="filtrosTareas" />
```

in methods I want with axios to extract from the JSON all the titles that contain 25; not only those that are exactly the value 25, but also those that put 125 or 255, but I cannot apply that type of condition:

```
 async filtrosTareas() {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/tareas`, {params:{titulo : this.filtrosTitulo }} );
     
      console.log(response.data);
      this.tareas = response.data;
```

Comment: We have no idea whether the API you're calling even supports that.

Comment: is a Json server

Comment: You've only typed `25` so why should it receive anything else?

Comment: precisely, I would like to know how to receive all the titles for example that contains 25 for example (25, 125, 256) and not only those that have the exact value. I test %25% but is not correct.

Comment: We can't tell you that. It may not be _possible_ with your API (I don't know what _"a Json server"_ means - https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonserver? Something else?)

Comment: Please don't put answers in the question - if you've solved the problem, post an actual answer below 

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it is not possible for us to know if the API you are using is capable of filtering on multiple params.

If you are happy to wear the cost of retrieving the entire json file then I would suggest filtering on the client.

```
 async filtrosTareas() {
   const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/tareas`);
   const filteredResponse = response.data.filter((row) => {
     return row.titulo === "25" || row.titulo === '125' || row.titulo === '255';
   });
  console.log(filteredResponse);
  this.tareas = filteredResponse;
 }
```

It is important to note in your example json the numbers are strings, so when using strict equality you must also define strings.